# Single sign on without a secret between the Site and Provider

Tags: architecture, single-sign-on

I have a client who wants single sign-on to my application and I'm trying to figure out how to implement it.

It seems that on a theoretical level, either a secret has to be shared between your site and the SSO provider so that messages can have anti-tampering hashes attached, or that your site has to generate a token which both the SSO and user ok independently.

I have an opportunity to tell the SSO provider how I would like to interact with them and I really don't want to deal with message hashing and storing secrets so I came up with the following which seems to me like it would work.

[image: SSO without a secret]

Is this insecure? Is there another/better way of doing this?

Comment: I cannot provide an answer, but some months ago I came across a Cisco WebEx whitepaper... might provide some ideas: http://developer.cisco.com/documents/4733862/4734214/Approaches+to+SSO.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The idea is good and it is very similar to the well known and production ready [Jasig](http://www.jasig.org/cas) [Central Authentication Service](http://www.jasig.org/cas) protocol, and its java server implementation [jcas](http://jcas.sourceforge.net/).

CAS handles also [Single Sign Out](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Single+Sign+Out) (which is not so obvious), [proxy](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Proxy+CAS+Walkthrough), [OAuth integration](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/OAuth), etc..